# The solutions of inequality

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve the inequality

```
x - 1 - (Log[x])/(Log[2]) < (1/Log[2]) Log[(1 + (Log[10^6] + Log[x] + x*Log[x/2])/Log[a])]
```

where `a:=3+2*Sqrt[2]`.

The commands `Reduce` and `NSolve` do not work on my computer.

Comment: The message from `Reduce` says it all: _This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce._ I doubt there's an analytic solution; for a numerical one, see [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155166/22013) below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define for simplicity

```
a = 3 + 2*Sqrt[2];
f[x_] := x - 1 - Log[x]/Log[2]
g[x_] := Log[1 + (Log[10^6] + Log[x] + x Log[x/2])/Log[a]]/Log[2]
```

Then

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

So the intersections are at

```
FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 0.1}]
```

> {x -> 0.0728923}

and

```
FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 8}]
```

> {x -> 8.03971}

Because you want to solve

$$f(x) < g(x)$$

then the solution is

$$x\in(0.0728923; 8.03971).$$

Comment: You could a domain restricted `Solve` as well: `Solve[f[x] == g[x] && -10 < x < 100, x]` will produce the intersection points.